# Best method to draw schedule grid on window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, binding

I have a ViewModel entirely setup using observable collections and am able to drill down in my interface to a specified schedule and want to display each day of the week and for each day i want to be able to display 96 different time slots (15 minute increments for 24 hours). Below is the ViewModel code as well as the View code.

My question is what is the best way to use a user control. I will want a user control for each day, so I will have 7 controls of the same kind per schedule, but I need someway to get my data-bound data into the user control. Do I need to make custom dependency properties and pass all 96 variables in?

If I do so once inside the control do I hard code out a grid with 96 columns and three rows and type each data piece into a corresponding rectangle?

My goal is to have a re-sizable schedule control that has the day of the week as text, the hours on the bottom and a color representation of each 15 minute. Each segment can be red, blue, or green, for example. Before with the grid and rectangles it would re-size with the window which was nice. Is there a better way to draw shapes on the screen? Canvas?

Thanks,
Wesley

```
public class ScheduleVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Schedule> schedules { get; set; }

    private static ScheduleVM viewModel = null;

    public static ScheduleVM getInstance()
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
            viewModel = new ScheduleVM();

        return viewModel;
    }

    private ScheduleVM()
    {
        schedules = new ObservableCollection<Schedule>();

        for (byte i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            schedules.Add(new Schedule());
    }
}

public class Schedule
{
    public ObservableCollection<Day> days { get; set; }

    public Schedule()
    {
        days = new ObservableCollection<Day>();

        for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            ObservableCollection<int> values = new ObservableCollection<int>();

            for (byte j = 0; j < 96; j++)
                values.Add(3);

            days.Add(new Day() { data = values });
        }
    }
}

public class Day : BaseVM
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> _data;
    public ObservableCollection<int> data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("data");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my current XAML

```
<ItemsControl Name="schedule">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <converters:OnOffColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter"/>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:Day data="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like this: bind your ItemsControl to Schedules, then in the template, build out a custom listbox with item source "days" and make that listbox's itemtemplate your day control? I haven't tested it out or know if it is the arrangement you meant, but here is a quick draft.

```
    <ItemsControl Name="schedule"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding schedules}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <converters:OnOffColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter"/>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding days}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:Day data="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I have something similar to that now, my problem is less with the data template part and more with how to structure the 'Day' class. Right now in my Day constructor I simply have a bunch of loops adding UI elements to a grid (text boxes, and rectangles). It works but causes an ever so slight lag on load and when I resize the window

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're looking for but your class seems fine unless you want to make "data" a list of classes like a "ScheduledEvent" class with a time and any info. Then bind to a listbox with a template similar to outlook with a time on each row or with a wrappanel itemspanel so that they can be blocks. Either way, another list would probably be better too since not everything is visible. If you use the horizontal list, you could also hold a class to group times (eg.by hour) to hold SchedultedEvent